# How to reuse this code and make it more dynamic

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm new to Javascript and although I can get by, I need to get smarter.

I have this code which is repeated about 7 times, the only thing that changes in the code is the `getMileagePrice`, `Mileage` and  `getMileageRate`, everything else is exactly the same.

I call this function using the 'google.script.run' command from Google Apps Scripts. `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getMileagePrice).getFeesArray();`

How can I reuse this so I'm using 6 lines of code rather than 42 lines of code(7 functions x 6 lines of code).

```js
function getMileagePrice(arrayOfValues) {
  var productName = 'Mileage';
  var filteredArrayOfValues = arrayOfValues.filter(function(r) {
    return r[0] === productName
  });
  getMileageRate = filteredArrayOfValues.reduce((amount, r) => amount + r[1], 0).toFixed(2)
  combinePrices();
}
```

Comment: No enough details to see what you mean

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
await getMileagePrice(arrayOfValues,productName)
```